# PHP parse Array-like String to Array

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I'm new to PHP but coming from Java & JavaScript. 
I have a string which I think resembles an Array?

```
[name] => John
[lastname] => Smith
[age] => 1.00
[amount] => 21.00
[birthday] => 6/9/2020
```

How would I parse this into an Array object so I can perform actions on each "key"?

parse_str() seems to fail with this, and so does explode() as it does not produce a "key-value" pair I can easily iterate over.

Comment: Could make a regex..

Comment: do you have control over the response? you could just use json, then you could just use the built in library for it to be converted into a data type on the other side

Comment: @Kevin can you elaborate a bit more? Do you mean converting strings to json instead of arrays? I have a test whether the input string is able to be decoded using json_decode(), the example above cannot sadly

Comment: @ChristianGarrovillo im not sure why would someone give a server response of a `print_r`, but if you have no control over it, you'll have to resort to a print_r converter of sorts, like the duplicate question above, there are answers in there that you could use

Comment: You need to do a bit of hacking to get that string to work with the function that was in the question I originally closed this with as it is **very** fussy about the input format. Here's a working example: https://3v4l.org/IGTCK

Comment: I basically just need to parse a string into a manipulable object  to perform actions on, my current solution is to convert a string to an array of key-value pairs. It does not need to conform to print_r(). The output will still be a string, just modified.

Comment: Is there a better way to approach this other than converting Strings to an Array?

Comment: The question is how do you get that string and why is it formatted that way?

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: The string is a sample input of possible incoming strings

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to manipulate that string to get it to parse into an array.  You can convert it to `ini` syntax:

```
$result = parse_ini_string(str_replace(['[', '=>'], ['data[', '='], $string))['data'];
```

Or you could convert to a query string and use `parse_str` or any number of other formats that would be more complex like JSON or quoting the keys and values and running `eval`:

```
eval('$result = [' . preg_replace('/\[([^[]+)\] => (.*)/', "'$1' => '$2',", $string)  . '];');
```

The best way would be to generate a usable format such as JSON instead of the format you have.

Comment: Would parsing the string to a JSON instead of an Array be a better way?

Comment: Doesn’t matter I meant getting it as JSON at the beginning would be better.